# Rename multiple folders using external string manipulation tool

Tags: command-line, find, rename

I am using [ccase](https://github.com/rutrum/convert-case).

The following command works.

```
$ mv camelCase (ccase -t Kebab camelCase)
```

Now I am trying to rename multiple directories using:

```
$ find . -type d -execdir rename 's/(.*)/$(ccase -t Kebab $1)/' '{}' \+
```

This does not work, I am receiving this error message:

```
Can't rename ./camelCase3 1000 4 24 27 30 46 121 132 1000ccase -t Kebab ./camelCase3): No such file or directory
```

What can I do?

Comment: Note that `mv camelCase (ccase -t Kebab camelCase)` is fish shell syntax. In Korn/POSIX-like shells, that should be: `mv camelCase "$(ccase -t Kebab camelCase)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
find . -depth ! -name . -type d -execdir sh -c '
  for dir do
    dir=${dir#*/} # remove the ./ prefix that some find implementations add
    new_dir=$(ccase -t Kebab -- "$dir") || continue
    [ "$dir" = "$new_dir" ] ||
      mv -i -- "$dir" "$new_dir"
  done' sh {} +
```

**Never** embed those `{}` in the *code* argument of `sh`/`bash` or any language interpreter, that would make it a command injection vulnerability. See [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008)

Some other  notes:

- when you can't guarantee variable data won't start with a `-`, use the `--` to mark the end of options. I don't known if `ccase` supports `--`, if it doesn't you can report it as a bug to their maintainers.
- no need for `bash` here, your system's `sh` should be enough
- in sh like in bash, parameter expansions and command substitutions must be quoted when in list context at least or otherwise they undergo split+glob! See for instance [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22565)
- Especially when doing something potentially destructive like calling `mv`, it's a good idea to check that each command you run succeeds. Here we use `|| continue` to skip dirs for which `ccase` fails.
- note the `+` instead of  `;` to pass several dirs to `sh` where possible which avoids having to call one shell per file. Not all `find` implementations that support that non-standard `-execdir` predicate will do it though. In some like on some BSDs or older versions of GNU `find`, `+` just does the same as `;` and the loop is then redundant (though harmless).
- beware that in `mv -- SomeDir some_dir`, if `some_dir` already exists and is a directory or a symlink to a directory, that becomes the same as `mv -- SomeDir some_dir/SomeDir`. With the GNU implementation of `mv`, that can be avoided with the `-T` option (or use `zmv` as below which will detect the clash)

To avoid that `-execdir`  and run as few shells as possible, you could use `-exec` instead but then you'd need to separate out the base name and the parent directory. As an improvement, we can also record failures of `ccase` or `mv` so it be reflected in `find`'s exit status:

```
find . -depth ! -name . -type d -exec sh -c '
  ret=0
  for dir do
    base=${base##*/}
    parent=${dir%/*}
    new_base=$(ccase -t Kebab -- "$base") && {
      [ "$base" = "$new_base" ] ||
        mv -i -- "$dir" "$parent/$new_base"
    } || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"' sh {} +
```

Note that above I'm adding a `-i` to `mv` to at least give the user an option to avoid data loss like when two files end up having the same new name. A better approach would be to use zsh's `zmv` which can check everything in advance and has a dry-run mode (`-n`):

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(*)(#q/)' '$1$(ccase -t Kebab -- $2)'
```

It also omits hidden files by default. It does a depth-first traversal by default. The `(#q/)` is the equivalent of `-type d`. In this case, the exit status of `ccase` is ignored. When the name is unchanged, there's no rename attempt.

You could replace `(*)` with `(^*-*)` to avoid processing files that already have hyphens in their name.

You could also probably do the conversion to Kebab case in zsh:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(*)(#q/)' \
       '$1${${${2//[_[:space:]]##/-}//(#b)([^[:upper:].-])([[:upper:]])/$match[1]-$match[2]}:l}'
```

Where we convert all sequences of whitespace or underscore to a single `-`,  insert `-`s in between non-uppercase (except `.`, and `-`) and uppercase characters in the base name, and convert the whole result to `l`owercase. You'd need to adapt if you want `AFileInTheUK.txt` to be renamed to `a-file-in-the-u-k.txt` instead of `afile-in-the-uk.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Rename directories one-by-one and start with the deepest first. E.g.

```
#!/bin/ksh93

find . -type d -depth -print | while read DIR ; do
    PREFIX=${DIR%/*}
    SUFFIX=${ ccase -t Kebab "${.sh.match:1}"; }
    print mv "${DIR}" "${PREFIX}/${SUFFIX}"
done
```

Remove the word **print** to arm the script after you have checked, that it does, what you want ;-).

Comment: You may want to read [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) and [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: Basically this is correct: if one has no control over the related directory and has no clue, how it and its sub dirs look like, one should not use any shell/CLI based tools like find to modify it. In this case one should write a proper tool in appropriate language like C, which passes dir entries as is (or should rather stay away from using this platform). However, here this seems to be not the case (indicated by using $1 as well as his solution)  and thus using the ksh93 is safe and a lot faster and much less resource consuming than the `find . ... -excedir sh -c ...` fork bomb ;-)

Answer (score 0):

OP here. The command I was looking for is:

```
find . -depth -type d -execdir bash -c 'mv {} $(ccase -t Kebab {})' \;
```