# Basename in find -exec

Tags: find, basename

I need use in find results full path and dir name.
This not work:

```
find ./1cv8 -maxdepth 1 -type d -wholename "./1cv8/*" -exec bash -c 'echo vrunner -src "{}" -o ./builds/"${basename "{}"}"' \;
```

error:

```
bash: ${basename "./1cv8/common"}: bad substitution
bash: ${basename "./1cv8/conf"}: bad substitution
bash: ${basename "./1cv8/x86_64"}: bad substitution
```

Please help

Comment: Do you mean `$(basename "{}")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate error is from using `${...}` in place of a command substitution, `$(...)`.  However, you also don't generally want to inject the pathname into the in-line shell script using `{}`, but instead to pass it as an argument to `bash -c`:

```bash
find ./1cv8 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c '
    echo vrunner -src "$1" \
        -o "./builds/$(basename "$1")"
    ' bash {} \;
```

or, for a slight speed increase from not starting a new shell for each match,

```bash
find ./1cv8 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        echo vrunner -src "$pathname" \
            -o "./builds/$(basename "$pathname")"
    done' bash {} +
```

This way, you will have no issues with names containing quotes or things that the shell will interpret as expansions, redirections, pipes etc., as the pathname is no longer injected and used as shell *code*.

Note that I deleted your `-wholename` test as it would always be *true*.

See also:

- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

In the `bash` shell, since you don't actually use `find` to locate the directories in any other directory than in the top-level one:

```bash
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

for pathname in ./1cv8/*; do
    if [ ! -d "$pathname" ] || [ -L "$pathname" ]; then
        # skip oven non-directories and symbolic links
        continue
    fi

    echo vrunner -src "$pathname" \
        -o "./builds/$(basename "$pathname")"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just switch to `zsh` and do:

```
for dir (1cv8/*(ND/)) vrunner -src $dir -o builds/$dir:t
```

with:

- `(ND/)` are glob qualifiers with:

  - `N`: nullglob: does not report an error if there's no match
  - `D`: include hidden files (like `find` does by default), you'd likely want to skip that unless you do want to process hidden dirs.
  - `/`: restrict the glob expansion to files of type *directory* (like `find`'s `-type d`).
- `$dir:t`: the `t`ail (basename) of the directory like in csh or vim.